# Atualizar o status de vários ids ao mesmo tempo Mysqli php mvc

Tags: php, mvc, phpmyadmin, checkbox, sql-update

Bom dia! Preciso "Pegar os Ids" selecionados e alterar os seus status para opção que escolher no select status. Edição em massa, o mesmo valor no campo status para todos Ids selecionados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: IDs selecionados]

**Models: Os_model**

```
 public function edit($table, $data, $fieldID, $ID)
{
    $this->db->where($fieldID, $ID);
    $this->db->update($table, $data);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() >= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Controllers: Os.php**

```
 public function alterarCheckbox(){

    $ids =  $this->input->post('status');
    $numRegs = count($ids);

    if($numRegs > 0){

        // atualiza status no banco de dados
        foreach($this->input->post('status') as $valor){
            $dados['status'] = 1;
            $this->db->where('idOs', $valor);
            if($this->db->update('os', $dados)){
                echo $valor." > Atualizado <br>";
            }
        }

    } else {
        echo "Nenhum item foi marcado.";
    }
}
```

**os.php**

```html
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" onSubmit="return valida_campos();">
  <?php echo form_hidden('idOs',$result->idOs) ?>

  <label for="status" class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select class="span2" name="status[<?php echo $res['id'] ?>]" id="status" value="">
      <option>status</option>
      <option <?php if ($result->status == 'Aguardando') { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="Aguardando">Aguardando</option>
      <option <?php if ($result->status == 'Liberado') { echo 'selected'; } ?> value="Liberado">Liberado</option>
    </select>

                          <span>
                             <button type="submit" class="btn" style="padding-top: px;border-top-width: px;margin-bottom: 9px;"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></button>
                          </span>
  </div>

/*input para conferir que os IDs foram selecionados*/
 <input class="span6" type="text" name="grupo_os" id="grupo_os" />

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input name="todos" id="todos" type="checkbox" value="todos" onchange="if(this.checked == true){marcacao_generico('form1',1,'os','grupo_os');}else{marcacao_generico('form1',0,'os','grupo_os');}" /> </th>
          <th>N° OS</th>
          <th>Campo 1</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
             
                        foreach ($results as $r) {


                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="os" value="'. $r->idOs. '" onclick="acao_coleta_generico(\''. $r->idOs. '\', \'grupo_os\' );"></td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $r->idOs . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $r->campo1 . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $r->status . '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                        } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

/*Código para CheckBox*/

<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['grupo_os']))
  {
    $os = '';
    $os = explode(",",str_replace(':','',$_POST['grupo_os']));
    ?>
  <br>
  <?PHP
    for($i = 0;$i < count($os) - 1; $i++)
      {
        echo($os[$i]);
        echo "<br>";
      }
    ?>
    <hr>
    <?PHP
  }
?>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function acao_coleta_generico(valor, campo_alvo) {
          if (document.getElementById(campo_alvo).value.indexOf(':' + valor + ':,') == -1) {
            document.getElementById(campo_alvo).value += ':' + valor + ':,';
          } else {
            var grupo = document.getElementById(campo_alvo).value;
            grupo = grupo.replace(':' + valor + ':,', '');
            document.getElementById(campo_alvo).value = grupo;
          }
        }

        function marcacao_generico(formulario, opcao, campo, campo_alvo) {
          for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById(formulario).elements.length; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById(formulario).elements[i].name == campo) {
              if (document.getElementById(formulario).elements[i].checked != opcao) {
                document.getElementById(formulario).elements[i].checked = opcao;
                acao_coleta_generico(document.getElementById(formulario).elements[i].value, campo_alvo);
              }
            }
          }
        }

        function valida_campos() {
          if (document.getElementById('grupo_os').value == '') {
            alert('Por favor, selecione ao menos um item.');
            return false;
          }

        }
      </script>
```

Comment: É impressão minha ou você cria vários elementos como o mesmo `id`?

Comment: @Augusto Vasques Como na tabela o Id é auto-increment cada vez que adiciono um registro gera um número de Id. Então não tenho como definir o Id que será gerado. Exemplo, registro n 1 sera gerado o Id 1, registro n. 2 será gerado Id 2. Não sei se foi essa a resposta esperada. Te agradeço pela atenção. Inseri uma imagem de como fica na minha página.

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro, mas se entendi correto, você pode usar `find_in_set` para fazer o update em todos os ids sem precisar montar loop.

```
update `TABELA` set status = 1
where find_in_set( cast( id as char ) , ? )
```

O `find_in_set` não funciona com os ids recebidos tipo input, então para contornar você usa `cast` tipo char